# Wordpress navigation menu items not shown correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I'm trying to move my navigation menu to wordpress and  I encountered a problem, that it's style is shown all wrong. After I move my code to worpdress  tag is automatically moved to the end of the code and applies same styling to all navigation bar elements. Maybe someone has a solution here or sees what's wrong with my code?

Here's my HTML code of the menu bar:

```
<div class="nav-links">
    <?php 
        $menu_settings = [
            'menu_class' => 'dropdown',
            'container' => false,
            'theme_location' => 'primary-navigation',

        ];
        wp_nav_menu($menu_settings);
        ?>

    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Apie festivalį</li>
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Naujienos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Apie festivalį</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Partneriai</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Organizatoriai</a></li>                           
            </ul>  
    </ul>

    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>72 val. iššūkis</li>
            <ul>   
                <li><a href="#">Apie iššūkį</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Taisyklės</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Komandos registracija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mentoriai ir komisija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Apdovanojimai</a></li>                           
            </ul> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the same code after I move it to Wordpress:

```
<div class="nav-links">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="dropdown">
        <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/sample-page/">Apie festivali</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-464" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-464"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/about-festivals/">Apie festivalį</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-481" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-481"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/category/one-news/">Naujienos</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-657" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-657"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/programa/">Programa</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-465" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-465"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/partners-page/">Partneriai</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-466" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-466"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/organizers-page/">Organizatoriai</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-84"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/sample-page/">72 val. iššūkis</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-467" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-467"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/about-challenge-page/">Apie iššūkį</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-538" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-538"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/rules-page/">Taisyklės</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-539" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-539"><a href="http://localhost/wp_odiseja/mentors-page/">Mentoriai ir komisija</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-704" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-704"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">Komandos registracija</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-540" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-540"><a href="#">Apdovanojimai</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's also my CSS code for navigation menu:

```
// =========================
.nav-links{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 60%;
}
.dropdown{
width: 100%;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
display: flex;
}
.dropdown li {
  display: flex;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;  
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', Bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:rgb(245, 240, 175);
  width: 100%;
  // img{
  //   width: 20px;
  //   height: 20px;
  //   padding-right: 0.42%;
  // }
  }
.dropdown ul{
  border: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(25, 105, 95, 0.8);
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', Bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 1.56% 1.82%;
}
.dropdown ul a {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  float: none;
  color: rgb(245, 240, 175);
  padding: 1.56% 1.82%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
//Menu hover--------------------------------------------------------------
 .nav-links:hover ul:hover li {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(245, 240, 175);
      }
      .dropdown ul a:hover {
        border-bottom: none;
        background-color: rgb(25, 105, 95);
      }
      .dropdown:hover ul {
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        border-bottom: none;
      }
     .nav-links:hover ul:hover  ul li{
        border-bottom: none;
      }
```

And here's my PHP, that I use to fetch HTMl and CSS on wordpress:

```
<div class="nav-links">
        <?php 
                $menu_settings = [
                    'menu_class' => 'dropdown',
                    'container' => false,
                    'theme_location' => 'primary-navigation',
                    // 'walker' => new custom_navwalker()
                ];
               wp_nav_menu($menu_settings);
            ?>
        </div>
```

Would be very grateful for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress themes usually style navigation menus already, you will need to move your CSS styles code for your menu as well and add it to your theme's custom CSS to override how it looks.  Do you have your CSS code?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. But that's the problem, that I already moved my CSS styles code for my menu to my theme's custom CSS, but it won't apply. My guess is, that it's connected to </li> tag, which is automatically moved to the end of code. If it would stay at the same place as in my HTML code, it should work. I cannot understand, why it's automatically moved to a different location. I added my CSS code to initial question.

Comment: Just to note, `//` does not comment out code in CSS/  you need to use `/*` and `*/`

Comment: Is this how you expect your navigation to look? https://jsfiddle.net/xjkgevf6/

Comment: Ok I took some time and looked it over.  Your new HTML wasn't in the same format as the older one.  Also I updated your CSS to fit it as well. You will need to update both CSS and HTML of your menu bar for this to work.  Here: https://jsfiddle.net/xjkgevf6/1/

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time and effort in helping me. I cannot move my html code directly to wordpress and I use PHP for it. After I move my initial code (number 1) via PHP to worpdress, it gets changed like that (number 2). And i cannot edit it directly and move </li> tag manually. I added my PHP to initial post, maybe there's something wrong with it? In my initial CSS and HTML everything's fine locally, but problems start after I move them to wordpress with PHP.

Comment: Thank you for all the input, I solved it finally after 2 weeks of trying. :)